# Unexpected output from mpi4py program

Tags: python, mpi, mpi4py

I'm new in MPI using Python and I'm having some issues here. This is my code:

```
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()

if rank == 0:
        a = 1 
        comm.bcast(a, root=0)
        s = comm.reduce(a, op=MPI.SUM)
        print 'From process 0, sum =', s
elif rank == 1:
        b = 2
        comm.bcast(b, root=1)  
        x = comm.reduce(b, op=MPI.SUM)
        print 'From process 1, sum =', x
```

I want to print: `From process PROCESS_NUMBER, sum = 3`

Process 0 prints correctly, but process 1 prints None.

I can't understand why. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Any collective operation (`Bcast`, `Reduce`) should be called on all
   processes, so it is incorrect to place it inside `if rank == N`
   statement.
2. In the second reduce you have to specify `root=1`.
3. Assignment is needed in broadcast `a = comm.bcast(a, root=0)`

Corrected code:

```
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()

if rank == 0:
        a = 1
else:
        a = None
a = comm.bcast(a, root=0)
s = comm.reduce(a, op=MPI.SUM)
if rank == 0:
        print 'From process 0, sum =', s

if rank == 1:
        b = 2
else:
        b = None
b = comm.bcast(b, root=1)
x = comm.reduce(b, op=MPI.SUM, root=1)

if rank == 1:
        print 'From process 1, sum =', x
```

Result of running on 3 processes:

```
From process 0, sum = 3
From process 1, sum = 6
```

Comment: Putting a collective inside a conditional is not intrinsically wrong: you could for instance skip the receive buffer of a `reduce` call on all processes but the root. As long as everyone agrees on the root and the shape of the buffers, it's fine to have some cases.

Answer (score 1):

`comm.reduce(a, op=MPI.SUM)` corresponds to [`MPI_Reduce()`](http://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.1/www3/MPI_Reduce.html) : the sum is only available on the root process.

If you wish the sum to be available on every process of the communicator, you can use `comm.allreduce(a, op=MPI.SUM)`. It corresponds to [`MPI_Allreduce()`](http://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.1/www3/MPI_Allreduce.html). See [this page](http://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/mpi-reduce-and-allreduce/) to know more about the difference between `MPI_Reduce()` and `MPI_Allreduce()`.